# shaders are not compiling

Tags: webgl

i have some problem maybe syntax maybe logic dont know but my shaders are not compiling when it passes through the console maybe someone knows whats happening, i followed the tutorial on youtube:[WebGl Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kB0ZVUrI4Aw)

```
var vertexShaderText = 
[
'precision mediump float;',
'',
'attribute vec2 vertPosition;',
'',
'void main()',
'{',
'gl_position = vec4(vertPosition,0.0,1.0);',
'}'
].join('\n');

var fragmentShaderText = 
[
'precision mediump float;',
'',
'void main()',
'{',
'gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);',
'}'
].join('\n');

var initDemo = function()
{
    console.log("this is working");
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

if(!gl)
{
    console.log("your browser doesnt support webgl, trying expermiental");
    gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
}

if(!gl)
{
    alert("your bwoser doesnt support webgl");
}

gl.clearColor(0,1,0,1);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// create shadders
var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

gl.shaderSource(vertexShader,vertexShaderText);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader,fragmentShaderText);

    console.log(fragmentShader);

if(!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
{
    console.error("Error compiling",gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
}

gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

var program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program,vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program,fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(program);

if(!gl.getProgramParameter(program,gl.LINK_STATUS))
{
    console.error("Error linking program",gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
    return;
}
gl.validateProgram(program);
  if(!gl.getProgramParameter(program,gl.LINK_STATUS))
{
    console.error("Error linking program",gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
    return;
}

var triangleVertices = 
[
    0.0,0.5,
    0.5,0.5,
    0.5,-0.5
]

var triangleVertexBufferObject = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,triangleVertexBufferObject);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(triangleVertices),gl.STATIC_DRAW);

var positionAtribLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program,'vertPosition');
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
 positionAtribLocation,
 2,
 gl.FLOAT,
 gl.FALSE,
 2 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
 0
);

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAtribLocation);

gl.useProgram(program);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES,0,3);   


}
```

Comment: Query `gl.getShaderInfoLog(...)` and you will get the compile error.

Comment: how can i do that? sorry but im kinda new :S

Comment: [you might want to look at this](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-boilerplate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Compilation errors for shaders can be queried using the following code:

```
var error_log = gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader);
console.log(error_log);
```

In your case, you have at least written `gl_position` instead of `gl_Position`.

Comment: yeah i catched that problem 1 min ago, seems like i have no problem with that code even on vertex even on fragment, but with my code verification the console.error catched me a problem :S

Comment: i thaught i had a error on compiling cause my triangle is drawing in a weird way :S

Answer (score -1):

GLSL Shaders need to be prefixed with `#version xxx` In order to compile.

For safety, when I write GLSL shaders, I usually write them like this:

```
#version 400 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(vertex, 1);
}
```

And I update the number if I need functionality that isn't available in GL4.0

Also, as another answer has already pointed out, you wrote `gl_position` instead of `gl_Position`

Comment: hmmm thank you, its really weird webgl at begin and i cant count with the intelissense of the editor

Comment: Not in WebGL 1.0  #version is not allowed.